# Connect to IOT device using c#

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, iot

I have a windows application and it generates an xml which I wish to write in the local folder of an IOT device.

So can anybody please help me that how I can connect to the IOT device through c# and place the file?

I have done it using remote UNC. Through I am connected to remote device and created a file share and I am able to save the file

Comment: Do you run the windows application on Raspberry pi? What's kind of your IOT device?

Comment: From Mrityunjay: *What is the size of your generated XML file and planned expected rate of data transmission for your application ?*

Comment: What OS? What have you tried? Do you get an error? Does your code run but the file doesn't appear? What do you mean `remote UNC` ? UNC is the file path format. *Does* your device support such paths in the first place ? *Did* you create a file share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it using remote UNC. Through I am connected to remote device and created a file share and I am able to save the file

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.